# CUDA: are access times for texture memory similar to coalesced global memory?

Tags: memory, cuda, global, textures

My kernel threads access a linear character array in a coalesced fashion. If I map
the array to texture I don't see any speedup. The running times are 
almost the same. I'm working on a Tesla C2050 with compute capability 2.0 and read
somewhere that global accesses are cached. Is that true? Perhaps that is why I
am not seeing a difference in the running time.

The array in the main program is

```
char *dev_database = NULL;
cudaMalloc( (void**) &dev_database, JOBS * FRAGMENTSIZE * sizeof(char) );
```

and I bind it to texture `texture<char> texdatabase` with

```
cudaBindTexture(NULL, texdatabase, dev_database, JOBS * FRAGMENTSIZE * sizeof(char) );
```

Each thread then reads a character `ch = tex1Dfetch(texdatabase, p + id)` where id
is `threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x` and `p` is an offset.

I'm binding only once and `dev_database` is a large array. Actually I found that
if the size is too large the bind fails. Is there a limit on the size of the array
to bind? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities for why you don't see any difference in performance, but the most likely is that this memory access *is not your bottleneck*.  If it is not your bottleneck, making it faster will have no effect on performance.

Regarding caching: for this case, since you are reading only bytes, each warp will read 32 bytes, which means each group of 4 warps will map to each cache line. So assuming few cache conflicts, you will get up to 4x reuse from the cache.  So if this memory access is a bottleneck, it is conceivable that the texture cache might not benefit you more than the general-purpose cache.

You should first determine if you are bandwidth bound and if this data access is the culprit.  Once you have done that, then optimize your memory accesses. Another tactic to consider is to access 4 to 16 chars per thread per load (using a char4 or int4 struct with byte packing/unpacking) rather than one per thread to increase the number of memory transactions in flight at a time -- this can help to saturate the global memory bus.

There is [a good presentation by Paulius Micikevicius from GTC 2010](http://www.gputechconf.com/gtcnew/on-demand-gtc.php#1073) that you might want to watch.  It covers both analysis-driven optimization and the specific concept of memory transactions in flight.

Comment: Thanks! The link you gave is quite helpful. It looks like diverging branches in my code are the bottleneck and now I'm trying to remove them. Any tips would be appreciated :)

Comment: How did you determine divergent branching is your bottleneck?  BTW if you think the answer is correct please accept it.

Comment: I timed the program in two ways. First I commented  all global memory reads and measured time. Then I uncommented global memory reads, commented instructions including if-else, and measured time. The time with first method was almost the same as the total time and the latter was much lower. Using this method I was able to pinpoint the exact if statements that are causing divergence.

Comment: Not a bad method as long as the changes don't change the amount of data accessed or the path taken through the code.